# Trimming Filenames from the end

Tags: bash, rename

I have a folder with following mp4 file which are needed to be renamed

```
for filename in /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*; do
    File1=$filename
    echo $File1
done
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Desal RO 16' Desalination Plants-JdN_Yx_5HzI.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/How Desalination Works-_H8EDLFNDtI.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/how membrane filter works with water-M3mpJysa6zQ.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Hydranautics - Spiral Wound Reverse Osmosis Elements-YlMGZWmh_Mw.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 1 of 3-6xD9FhbAIvY.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 2 of 3-Dt23yzCXaVA.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 3 of 3-VXyK20P6HD4.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/MED Desalination Process-5nDcxhkq8Js.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Membrane Replacement Procedure-zNXYkH3uj-I.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis or RO System-BeXHKpuHVZg.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Pressure Vessel-BeXHKpuHVZg.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/RO Process Equipments by R S Engineering, Mumbai-ijJ6QyaQ-Bk.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/The BioSand Water Filter-SlqAitfBbdQ.mp4
```

Now I want to trim the random words starting from **-** till **.mp4** such that this filename is converted from 
`The BioSand Water Filter-SlqAitfBbdQ.mp4` to `The BioSand Water Filter.mp4`

for this I got partial success as is shown below

```
for filename in /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*; do
    File1=$filename
    Out=${File1:0:${#File1}-16}".mp4"
    echo $Out
done
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Desal RO 16' Desalination Plants.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/How Desalination Works.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/how membrane filter works with water.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Hydranautics - Spiral Wound Reverse Osmosis Elements.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 1 of 3.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 2 of 3.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 3 of 3.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/MED Desalination Process.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Membrane Replacement Procedure.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis or RO System.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Pressure Vessel.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/RO Process Equipments by R S Engineering, Mumbai.mp4
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/The BioSand Water Filter.mp4
```

Now when I add the last piece, it boils down to nothing?

```
for filename in /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*; do
    File1=$filename
    Out=${File1:0:${#File1}-16}".mp4"
    echo $Out
    mv $filename $Out
done
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Desal RO 16' Desalination Plants.mp4
mv: target ‘Plants.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/How Desalination Works.mp4
mv: target ‘Works.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/how membrane filter works with water.mp4
mv: target ‘water.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Hydranautics - Spiral Wound Reverse Osmosis Elements.mp4
mv: target ‘Elements.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 1 of 3.mp4
mv: target ‘3.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 2 of 3.mp4
mv: target ‘3.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Industrial Reverse Osmosis Startup Part 3 of 3.mp4
mv: target ‘3.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/MED Desalination Process.mp4
mv: target ‘Process.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Membrane Replacement Procedure.mp4
mv: target ‘Procedure.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis or RO System.mp4
mv: target ‘System.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/Reverse Osmosis Pressure Vessel.mp4
mv: target ‘Vessel.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/RO Process Equipments by R S Engineering, Mumbai.mp4
mv: target ‘Mumbai.mp4’ is not a directory
/media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/The BioSand Water Filter.mp4
mv: target ‘Filter.mp4’ is not a directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your file names contain spaces, you need to quote them before passing them to `mv` in order to avoid [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html):

```
 ... mv "$filename" "$Out" ...
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the filenames are all in this format:

```
filename-RandString.mp4
```

If so, you can simply delete everything from the last `-` to `.mp4`:

```
for f in /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*-*mp4; do
    mv "$f"  "${f%-*mp4}.mp4"; 
done
```

The format `${string%substring}` deletes the shortest match of `$substring` from the back of `$string`.

---

You can also do this using (Perl) `rename`:

```
rename 's/-[^-]*?mp4$/.mp4/' /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*-*mp4
```

Comment: I think you want `${string%substring}` (the shortest match), otherwise it will truncate `Hydranautics - Spiral Wound Reverse Osmosis Elements-YlMGZWmh_Mw.mp4` into `Hydranautics\ .mp4`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti argh, so I do. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: @terdon - you can use `rename` for this too.

Comment: is the `:` a typo?

Comment: @bersch yes, it as left from my test case which ran `echo "$f : "${f%-*mp4}.mp4"`.

Comment: @slm I know, but since there are often issues between the to `rename` implementations, I tend to avoid it in answers unless the OP states their distro so I can know which one they have.

Comment: @terdon - the only reason I mentioned it was b/c he tagged the Q w/ it. But yeah, I just tried to use it the other day and was kicking myself the whole time b/c of the inconsistencies w/ the implementations.

Comment: @slm I added one that works for the Perl version I have on Debian.

Comment: @terdon Have you tested your `rename` command? I believe it will delete everything from the first `-` to the end of the file name.

Comment: @JosephR. OK,I'm having a really bad day :). Thanks, fixed.

Comment: +1 good answer. You might want to make the file list more restrictive: `for f in /media/usama/CRUNCH/RO_Plant/RO_Videos/*-*.mp4`

Comment: @glennjackman true, done.